# ListeningIOReactor encountered a checked exception : Too many open files

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are facing a strange issue in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 with below error. After we start the server, server is respondin but it's not accepting any http requests. Below is the error. We are just testing 20-50 reqeusts...

```
2016-06-17 13:13:15,330 [-] [PassThrough HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher Listener]  WARN PassThroughHttpListener System may be unstable: HTTP ListeningIOReactor encountered a checked exception : Too many open files
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:241)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:170)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:153)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:349)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager$1.run(PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager.java:506)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

Comment: Did you try increasing file open limit? Eg: ulimit -f 65000

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when you burst the ESB with lot of requests, and the ESB does not close the connections properly. Then all the file descriptors associated with those stale connections remains as it is and gets exhausted. If you have disabled the keep-alive then there's a high tendency for this issue to occur.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to increase the number of file handles & maximum allowable number of open file descriptors to fix the above issue.**

**Check for the maximum number of file handle and currently in use**
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr

Change it to a value recommended by WSO2 (can change case to case)
**sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536**

**For open file descriptors**
ulimit -n

**To change this limit, edit the /etc/security/limits.conf file**

*** soft nofile 4096
* hard nofile 65535**

For a comprehensive list, please refer
**https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Network+and+OS+Level+Performance+Tuning**